# Python, self.alpha = alpha ran in function, but not found when calling self.alpha in its class

Tags: python

This is pretty weird since I have no idea what should I call this error.

So basically, I'm trying to input the file from another module

file1 (Input)

```
from file2 import Module2   

class Module1():
    def app_name(self,name):
        p = Module2()
        p.app_name(name)

    def app_directory(self,directory):
        p = Module2()
        p.app_directory(directory)
        
m = Module1()
m.app_name("app")
m.app_directory("path/to/app")
```

file2 (getting)

```
class Module2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.directory = None
        
    def app_name(self,name):
        self.name = name
        
    def app_directory(self,directory):
        self.directory = directory
        self.pr()
    
    def pr(self):
        print(self.name,self.directory)
```

After being executed, It gave me self.name = None just like what it is in **init**, but self.directory is what I typed in. I spent hours but still can't figure out what is the problem, I really need help.

Comment: Both methods in `Module1` create a brand-new instance of `Module2`, set an attribute on that instance, and then throw the instance away.  There is no lasting effect, because the object containing the attribute no longer exists.  `Module1` needs to create a single instance of `Module2` (in its `__init__()`, most likely), save it in some `self.X` attribute, and use that instance for everything else.

Comment: @Ten kho I added an answer please clarify what is your goal; then I can provide the correct answer.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks for your knowledge, I forgot to create a self.x in my parent __init__ file, I just simply write in def: d = class and then return d that creates a new instance every time my app's event changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is pretty normal, you are not keeping track of `p` created in `Module1` `app_name`, In other words, you are creating 2 separate objects:

If you want `p` you should do this:

```
from file2 import Module2   

class Module1():
    def app_name(self,name):
        self.p =Module2()
        self.p.app_name(name)

    def app_directory(self,directory):
        # p = Module2()
        self.p.app_directory(directory)
        
m = Module1()
m.app_name("app")
m.app_directory("path/to/app")
```

return :

```
app path/to/app
```

Comment: Ah yes, that's work perfect. I remember trying your solution before without knowing about split instances. Your example makes me realize that I need to change d  = class.def() into self.d = class_def() in my parent __init__ file.